# Replace string with incremented value in BATCH

Tags: string, batch-file, search, replace

First of all I am new to coding and hope you can find some help here .

I 'm trying to make a batch script to solve a simple problem.

I want to give an argument to the script, which contains a wildcard anywhere in the word and the script detect it and replace it with an incremental value given by a for loop.

This is what i have until now, but the problem is that there is not incremental result yet.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set SEARCHTEXT=?
set string=%1

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 5) do (
    set REPLACETEXT=%%x
    call set string=%%string:!SEARCHTEXT!=!REPLACETEXT!%%
    echo !string!
)
:end
```

by example if i save this as "example.bat" and run this is what i get

```
> example.bat num?
```

the result is...

```
num1
num1
num1
num1
num1
```

but this should be...

```
num1
num2
num3
num4
num5
```

Could you help me?

Comment: `for /l %%x in (1, 1, 5) do echo !string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%%x!`

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `string` and it loses `?`.

Put the result into a new variable instead.

```dos
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 5) do (
    set "string2=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%%x!"
    echo !string2!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reinitialising `string` at every itération will work too :

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set SEARCHTEXT=?

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 5) do (
    set "string=%1"
    set string=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%%x!
    echo !string!
)
```